# Subrings $A$ of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ such that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{F}_p[x]/A=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-fields, polynomial-rings

> Suppose we have the ring $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ of polynomials with coefficients in the Galois field with $p$ prime number elements. I want to find all subrings $A$ containing the identity such that when considered as vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the quotient $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/A$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$. Also want to find the isomorphism classes of these subrings.

So far I have only been able to find one subring: the ring generated by $1,x^2,x^3$. I know that if $x\in A$, then $A=\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, so I don't want $n\cdot x$ to be in $A$. After this, trying to find other subrings, it becomes really messy from my point of view. So I don't think this might be a good way to approach the problem.

It also seems to me that we can view this as an extension problem:
$$0\rightarrow A\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_p\rightarrow 0$$
And for groups, I know that using the second homology group would help if I were given $Q$ and $N$ but not $G$ in the following sequence:
$$0\rightarrow N\rightarrow G\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 0$$
My questions are if there is a standard method for computing $N$ given $G$ and $Q$, and if these methods generalize to ring extensions? Any help would be appreciated, specially references to literature.

Comment: The rings generated by $1, (x-a)^2, (x-a)^3$ for $a\in \Bbb F_p$ all work the same way $1, x^2, x^3$ does. So now you have $p$ subrings.

Comment: How did you know they would work so quickly?

Comment: Mapping $x$ to $x-a$ is an isomorphsim of $\Bbb F_p[x]$. Geometrically, if you're drawing the graphs of all the polynomials in $A$, I'm just sliding the coordinate system horizontally. This doesn't change which graphs are products and sums of which other graphs, only what expression we attach to each of them. (Of course, polynomials are more than their graphs, and this is especially true over finite fields, where several polynomials may have identical graphs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building upon the ideas from Dirk's answer (+1) and Arthur's comment under the question.

The subring $A$ cannot contain a polynomial of degree $1$ because, as an $\Bbb{F}_p$-algebra, it would then contain $x$ and be equal to $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$. As Dirk pointed out, this implies that $\Bbb{F}_p[x]=A\oplus x\Bbb{F}_p$, and consequently there exist unique constants $a_2$ and $a_3$ such that
$$
P=x^2-a_2x, Q=x^3-a_3x\in A.
$$
It is straightforward to verify that these polynomials satisfy the relation
$$
Q^2=P^3+3a_2PQ-2a_3P^2+(a_2^3-a_2a_3)Q+(a_3^2-a_2^2a_3) P. (*)
$$
Such a relation has to exist because the space of polynomials of degree $\le6$ in $A$ and vanishing at $x=0$ has dimension five, so the set of six polynomials $P^3,Q^2,QP,P^2,Q,P$ must be linearly dependent. Finding the relation was then simple linear algebra.

The equation $(*)$ implies that the $\Bbb{F}_p[P]$-module
$$
\tilde{A}=\Bbb{F}_p[P]+Q\Bbb{F}_p[P]
$$
is actually a subring. The main point is that $(*)$ proves that $\tilde{A}$ is stable under multiplication by $Q$.

It follows easily that the set
$$
\mathcal{B}=\{P^i\mid i\in\Bbb{N}\}\cup\{QP^i\mid i\in\Bbb{N}\}
$$
is an $\Bbb{F}_p$-basis for $\tilde{A}$. Because the collection $\mathcal{B}$ has monic polynomials of degrees $0,2,3,4,\ldots,$ it follows that $\tilde{A}$ has codimension one in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$.

Obviously $\tilde{A}\subseteq A$ so we can conclude that $A=\tilde{A}$. Equally obviously distinct choices of $a_2,a_3$ give rise to distinct subspaces $\tilde{A}$, so we arrive at the answer:

> Every such subgring $A$ is determined by two parameters $a_2,a_3\in\Bbb{F}_p$ when the ring $A$ is generated by $x^2-a_2x$ and $x^3-a_3x$. Different choices for the parameters give rise to different subrings $A$.

---

A few closing remarks:

- Dirk was definitely on the right track. He may have missed the relation $$P^2+2a_2Q-a_2^2P=x^4+(a_2^3-2a_2a_3)x,$$ that ties his $a_4$ to $a_2$ and $a_3$. Similarly, we can tie all $a_i, i>4$, to $a_2,a_3$.
- Arthur was also on the right track, but missed a few possibilities. Also, when $p=2$, all the monomials $(x-a)^2$ have linear coefficient zero, so we get more. Particularly as...
- ... the argument seems to generalize to fields other than prime fields of a positive characteristic.

Comment: Hopefully many of you recognize the argument leading to the existence of $(*)$ from  the theory of elliptic curves, when Riemann-Roch applied to the divisors $mP_\infty, m=0,2,3,\ldots$,  similarly lead to Weierstrass form of the curve.

Comment: +1 Great answer; I was attempting to write up something similar, but your approach is much more clear and concise, and provides some wonderful context hidden in the  remarks and comment :)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the detailed answer! A lot of these arguments are going over my head. Is there any book you'd recommend on Elliptic Curves emphasizing computation so that I can arrive to something like this more naturally? My background consists of a course and a half of algebraic geometry (right now seeing schemes) and some commutative algebra up to chapter 5 of matsumura.

Comment: @K.Takeuchi I'm sad to say I'm mostly ignorant about algebraic geometry. However, curves and related field/rings form a much simpler subset of AG. I might recommend [Michael Rosen's nice book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953359). Particularly if you have seen any (algebraic) number theory. Spotting structures like $\tilde{A}$ as $\Bbb{F}_p[P]$ becomes then easy. If you haven't seen ANT (or may be have an interest in telcomm applications), then [Stichtenoth](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540768777) might be a better match.

Comment: I would expect a well-stocked math library near you to have at least one of those. There is an earlier paperback version of Stichtenoth, which is very much ok (I only own a copy of that and, of course also Rosen).

Answer (score 4):

As all powers of $x$ are linearly independent, the only chance to get what you want is to have all but one power of $x$ contained in your ring $A$, plus maybe lower order terms.
However, if your ring $A$ contains $x$, then it also contains $x^2,x^3$, etc., so it is directly the whole of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Therefore, $A$ can't contain $x$.

But that means that $A$ must contain elements $y_i = x^i + a_ix$ for all $i \geq 2$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{F}_p$. On the other hand, every choice of such elements $y_i$ will give you a ring $A$ with the desired properties. Now I think every choice of the sequence $(a_i)_{i \geq 2}$ will give a different, non-isomorphic (as rings) versions of $A$, but it might be better if you properly check that.

Comment: I will try that thanks! I will mark this as answered if I can verify all of the statements are true.

Comment: For any quadratic $x^2+bx+c$ then $A = \Bbb{F}_p+ (x^2+bx+c) \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ is a subring and $A+ x\Bbb{F}_p = \Bbb{F}_p[x]$. Do you see other kind of $A$ ? @K.Takeuchi