# finite codimensional subalgebra of $\mathbb C[z]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $p_1, p_2$ are two polynomials in $\mathbb C[z]$, then when $\mathbb C[p_1, p_2]$ is finite codimensional in $\mathbb C[z]$? Are there some sufficient conditions (or NASC) on $p_1, p_2$?

It is apparently clear that if $p_1 = p_2$, $\deg p_1>1$, then it is not finite codimensional. For example, take $\mathbb C[z^2]$.

Comment: Certainly not always, e.g. $p_1=p_2=z^2$.

Comment: I recall seeing a related discussion either here or on MathOverflow. The only thing I could find right away was [particular to codimension one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220597/11619).

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson, I agree. I edited my question before I see your comment.

Comment: IIRC there is either a result or a conjecture that the counterexamples have the form $p_1=r_1(q)$, $p_2=r_2(q)$ for some polynomials $r_1,r_2,q$, $\deg q>1$. These trivially have infinite codimension, but the other direction is anything but obvious (to me at least).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, would it be possible to suggest some reference around this question.

Comment: Not from me, I'm afraid. That's why the recollections are vague.